# Is there a way to "git diff" a google drive folder?

Tags: git, google-drive-api, google-client

I managed to use gdrive cli to upload files/folders to google drive,

`gdrive upload  -p <googledrivekey> /path/to/folder`

however each upload would not update the same-named folder but conducts a separate upload, making the folders accumulate. 
Is there a way to sort of version control the folder, then conduct update and delete like `git diff` / `git merge`?

gdrive cli github repo:

https://github.com/gdrive-org/gdrive

Comment: Why are you not using the google drive client that uses **synchronization** to manage the drive?

Comment: good question. the environment is a linux server though, is it applicable?

Comment: Other than 3rd party, no. Google Drive is not a git repository, and if all you have is an upload tool, then git won't work over that either. You either have to live with this tool, change to a different tool, or pick one of the 3rd party synchronization clients for Google Drive (there's a few for Linux if my memory serves me right, but none of them official). However, git runs locally, or can talk to a remote git hosted repository, but Google Drive is not such a thing, so that won't work.

Comment: TL;DR If the only tool you can use to upload to the drive is creating new folders, and you have no other means of communicating with the server, then you're limited in what you can do.